# Can any two points in an open and connected subspace of a locally convex t.v.s. be connected by a continuously differentiable path?

Tags: connectedness, topological-vector-spaces, path-connected

Can any two points in an open and connected subspace of a Hausdorff locally convex space be connected by a continuously differentiable path?

Some known related facts:

An open and connected subspace of a locally convex space is path-connected ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766422/when-does-open-and-connected-imply-path-connected), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2774148/open-and-connectedness-on-the-topological-vector-space-over-mathbbr-implies)).

In a connected smooth manifold every two points can be connected by a continuously differentiable path ([3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45976/connectivity-path-connectivity-and-differentiability), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243295/smooth-curves-on-a-path-connected-smooth-manifold)).